# Burning Digispark bootloader without an Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, attiny, digispark

I've been wondering if there is any method to burn a Micronucleus bootloader into a blank ATtiny85 Digispark using just Windows or a Linux distro, and not needing another Arduino board such as UNO that acts as ISP.

Comment: it will be hard even with programmer or other Arduino. only other option is a wiring on computers parallel connector. but most new computers don't have it.

Comment: I've found some guides about how to burn the bootloader using an UNO and the process doesn't seem to be very hard, my trouble here is that i don't have an UNO at the moment so i'm looking for alternative ways to do it. Could you explain which would be the way to go using a parallel connector?

Comment: the Digispark doesn't have reset pin. that will be a complication

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Simplest-AVR-Parallel-port-programmer/

Comment: [Here](https://www.elecrom.com/make-your-own-ultra-simple-universal-avr-programmer/) are some more simple programmers (including serial port, which may be easier to find).

Comment: it crossed my mind that a USB keyboard has three outputs ... a quick search found this ... https://hackaday.com/2012/11/26/usb-keyboard-becomes-an-avr-programmer/

Comment: @Vile Did you managed to burn the bootloader using the Arduino? I ran into the same issue.